# Where can I get a CustomerKey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Trying to do a trigger send with the ExactTarget SOAP API, but I can not figure out what a [CustomerKey](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/exacttarget_for_appexchange_api_guide/properties/customerkey/) is. Where do I find this?

Answer (score 5):

The customer key is the unique identifier for a particular object across your account.  So, if you created a data extension in the app, you will see a field called "external key".  That's the Customer Key:

[image]

Comment: "CustomerKey: User-supplied unique identifier for an object within an object type (corresponds to the external key assigned to an object in the user interface)." [source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exacttarget.meta/exacttarget/node_3177.htm?language=en)

Comment: @Timothy what if I don't see a Data Extensions under Subscribers?

Comment: Almost all object has an External Key field, so in case I wasn't clear, the data extension was just an example of where you might see them.  If you'd actually like use Data Extensions and they're not there, talk to your ET representative to get them enabled.

Comment: I am trying to trigger a welcome email. I have tried the External Keys for the email as the Customer Key but still getting errors. Is this key maybe for the user and not the email? Or what should I be looking for. None of this really makes sense.

Comment: @corbanb The triggered send interaction will have a customer/external key to use in the api call. If you don't see Data Extensions and need them turned on, contact your account rep.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews - do I need data extensions to trigger a send email? I guess that's not clear. I see the external key on my email lists but that one didn't work for the trigger send. Sorry just having a hard time finding clear info on what it is I need to do this step. Thanks.

Comment: @corbanb The pieces you need are all on [this page](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers/).  You can send a triggered email using lists or data extensions. Most choose data extensions because they perform a bit better over time, but it's not a requirement and lists still do really well also.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews - I have put in just about anything I could think of [here](http://cl.ly/image/0S3U1O2a3j2n ) and not seeing the API work. Thoughts? This is for my list.

Comment: @corbanb I have no idea what you are doing. Maybe we can set up a screen share to go through this. I'm not sure you are on the right track.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews - how can I contact you?

Comment: Shoot me an email kelly@kellyjandrews.com